# Closing a Faulted channel in CoreWcf

Tags: c#, corewcf

I am using CoreWCF to create a proxy and if I run into situations where the channel is faulted, I can't re-create the proxy. I've tried Abort()'ing the channel, disposing the proxy, disposing the channel, I've tried wrapping it in a DispatchProxy, I'm not sure what I'm missing here.

Once a channel is created, within a process, subsequent calls to create will return an already faulted channel:

```cs
         var binding = GetDefaultNetTcpBinding();
         var ep = new EndpointAddress(new Uri(url), new System.ServiceModel.SpnEndpointIdentity(""));

         var factory = new ChannelFactory<T>(binding, ep);
         var proxy = factory.CreateChannel();
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the proxy (and/or its faulted channel) has actually been disposed, and that you are not unintentionally keeping it around and reusing it.

Comment: You're right, what I was seeing were not related to being unable to create a new proxy. The code that retried was:

```T1 DoWithRetry<T1>(Func<T1> func, int retries)
{
   try
   {
      return func();
   }
   catch (Exception e)
   {
      _proxy.Abort();
      _proxy = CreateNewProxy();
      return DoWithRetry(func, retries-1);
   }
   throw new Exception("Failed");
}
```

And the problem was that I was calling in `DoWithRetry(_proxy.ServiceCall, 3)`, which held onto the _proxy and kept calling the faulted channel, even though _proxy itself was being recreated.